# Fatal Error: Main. Application Forced closed

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adb, fatal-error

Im designing my first android application and keep coming up with the following error which is draining the life out of me and I do not understand it very well (Please find my Logcat (verbose), Java Code(this i played around with and this began to occur once started to work on my editButton and buttonUpdate bit. Does it have anything to do with the editStatus? I really think it may) and I have also put in my manifest file:

**LOGCAT verbose**

```
04-21 15:30:23.388: D/AndroidRuntime(276): Shutting down VM
04-21 15:30:23.388: W/dalvikvm(276): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.locator.demo/com.locator.demo.LocatorDemoActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.locator.demo.LocatorDemoActivity.onCreate(LocatorDemoActivity.java:21)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-21 15:30:23.427: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
04-21 15:35:23.607: I/Process(276): Sending signal. PID: 276 SIG: 9
04-21 15:50:32.127: D/AndroidRuntime(301): Shutting down VM
04-21 15:50:32.127: W/dalvikvm(301): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.locator.demo/com.locator.demo.LocatorDemoActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at com.locator.demo.LocatorDemoActivity.onCreate(LocatorDemoActivity.java:21)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-21 15:50:32.147: E/AndroidRuntime(301):  ... 11 more
```

**CODE:**

```
package com.locator.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class LocatorDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText editStatus;
    Button buttonUpdate;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.locationstatus); 

        editStatus = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_status);
        buttonUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_update);
        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

                //have button 'listen' for click

    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**ANDROID Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.locator.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_main" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LocatorDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I have;**

attempted to do adb kill-server and adb start-server and run it with an without an emulator as suggested in another post.  Please be slightly understanding as my knowledge of eclipse and Java is pretty low and im learning.

Please help

Comment: can you post your xml file. looks like you have textview in xml and you are typecasting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen from this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
>   ComponentInfo{com.locator.demo/com.locator.demo.LocatorDemoActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

And this one:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

You are trying to cast a `TextView` to `EditText` ( in this line: `editStatus = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_status);`).

Go to **locationstatus.xml**, and change the `TextView` with the id `edit_status` to `EditText`.

Comment: I made the changes in the xml file and java file though am still getting the errors.

Comment: This is what I changed: android:id="@+id/edit_text" did I change the wrong thing?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the `<TextView ..` to `<EditText...` in the XML file.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand what you mean and why.  However since I have done that I came across this 'R cannot be resolved to a variable' for these two lines setContentView(R.layout.locationstatus); 
        
editStatus = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_status); in my java file.  I made sure that 'Import R Android' was not involved.  Any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Clean and revuild the project, it should fix the problem (give it a few moments, as it automatically generates R)

Comment: I tried a restarted the project.  No such luck.. and 'Note: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an "import android.R" statement at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete them.' does not seem to be the issue.. Are there any other causes for this error do you know?

Comment: No, AFAIK - only clean, rebuild and remove `import android.R` if exist.